# Having trouble updating global variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, do-while

I'm having trouble updating a global variable in my Node app.  Can someone look at my code and let me know what's going wrong?  I've defined a dowhile loop to run as long as my HTTP response object does not have "next" defined.  Inside the loop, things are running as expected and new_json.next is defined, but the while condition is returning an error because new_json.next is undefined there.  I'm a little new at Javascript, so somehow my variable scope is off, but I can't figure out how to do things correctly based on other questions.

```
    function make_pagination_request(json, create_response_data) {    


        var new_json={};
        do {    

            var options = {
                 host: slug + '.nationbuilder.com',  //should be replaced to be site-agnostic
                 path: json.next,
                 method: "GET",
                 json: true,
                 headers: {
                     "content-type": "application/json",
                     "accept": "application/json"
                 },
            }    

            var req = https.get(options, req_callback);    


            function req_callback(response) {
                response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    str += chunk;
                });    

                response.on('end', function(new_json) {    

                    new_json=JSON.parse(str);
                    new_results = new_json.results
                    results= results.concat(new_results);
                    console.log("combinedlength: " + results.length)
                    console.log(new_json.next);


                });
            }
        } while (new_json.next.includes("api"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the HTTPs request is asynchronous while the do/while cycle is synchronous. In this case the while statement is reached before a value containing `next` is assigned to the `new_json` variable.

When the while statement is reached the first time the callback function hasn't been called yet. Therefore the value of `new_json` is `{}` (the initial value) and it lack `next`. Therefore the error you are experiencing.

But the solution is not fixing the initial value of `new_json`. The solution is to remove the do/while loop and continue work inside the HTTPs request callback.

Comment: I should've known it was something like that.  This is something I'm only beginning to understand and it's been the root of some of my other problems.  I ended up simply calling the function, make_pagination_request, from the end of itself.

Comment: The asynchronic nature of Javascript code and the synchronic constructs included in the language has been a great source of problems for a lot of programmers. I see in your comment that you manage to solve the problem by calling the same function again. Even if it works i recommend you into researching a better solution because if the function call itself many times you will reach a stack overflow issue.

Comment: that's a joke. I'll probably leave it as is for now, but worry about that if the function will be running many times (it should only be about 10 times max with the current database)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code that I got working. Thanks yeiniel.   I ended up simply calling the function, make_pagination_request, from the end of itself. I also made some other changes that weren't related to the original problem but were necessary for debugging.

```
    function make_pagination_request(json, create_response_data, callback, tokens, options) {        

            path = json.next + "&access_token=" + tokens[slug];    


            var options = {
                 host: slug + '.nationbuilder.com',  //should be replaced to be site-agnostic
                 path: path,
                 method: "GET",
                 json: true,
                 headers: {
                     "content-type": "application/json",
                     "accept": "application/json"
                 },
            }    

            var str='';        

            var req = https.get(options, req_callback);        


            function req_callback(response, create_response_scripts) {
                response.on('data', function(chunk) {    

                    str += chunk;
                });        

                response.on('end', function() {  

                    new_json=JSON.parse(str);
                    new_results = new_json.results
                    results= results.concat(new_results);
                    console.log('combined_length: ' + results.length)


                    if (new_json.next) {
                        make_pagination_request(new_json, create_response_data,create_response_scripts, tokens, options);
                    } else {
                        create_response_data(results, query, create_response_scripts);
                    }


                });
            }
        }
```